# How to draw a custom shape using multiple lines

Tags: java, android, drawing

I wanted to draw the custom shape using multiple straight lines. For that, i used the canvas. But I can draw only one line. When I draw second, previous disappears.
My code is given.

```
public class CanvasBackground extends View {

public Paint paint;
public Context context;
public Canvas canvas;
public ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
float scalfactor = 1f;
boolean isDrawing;
private PointF startPoint, endPoint;

public CanvasBackground(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    paint = new Paint();
    scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new CanvasScale());
    setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    this.canvas = canvas;
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    canvas.save();
    DrawingZoomingCanvas(canvas);
    DrawingLine(canvas);

    canvas.restore();
    Log.e("OnDraw >>>", "CALLING");
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startPoint = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
            endPoint = new PointF();
            isDrawing = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (isDrawing) {
                endPoint.x = event.getX();
                endPoint.y = event.getY();
                invalidate();
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (isDrawing) {
                endPoint.x = event.getX();
                endPoint.y = event.getY();
                //isDrawing = false;
                invalidate();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    //scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    Log.e("OnTouch >>>", "CALLING" + isDrawing);
    return true;
}

//drawing Matrix Canvas With Zoom
private void DrawingZoomingCanvas(Canvas canvas) {
    //drawing Matarix
    canvas.translate(scalfactor * 10, scalfactor * 10);
    canvas.scale(scalfactor, scalfactor);
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(220, 220, 220));
    for (int i = 0; i <= canvas.getHeight() * scalfactor; i += 10) {
        canvas.drawLine(i, 0, i, canvas.getHeight(), paint);
        canvas.drawLine(0, i, canvas.getWidth(), i, paint);
    }
}

//drawing a line
private void DrawingLine(Canvas canvas) {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    if (isDrawing)
        canvas.drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y, paint);

}

private class CanvasScale extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        scalfactor *= scaleGestureDetector.getScaleFactor();
        scalfactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scalfactor, 10.0f));
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: which shape you want to draw

Comment: any custom shape. It's not final.

Comment: Have you find the code?

Comment: i tried it. worked. But i wanted to set on click listener on line

Answer (score 0):

You are clearing your canvas each time you draw a line, so the previous line will be erased as you draw the new one.

You need to store the previous lines in a bitmap so you can draw these when you draw the new one.

Comment: Thank you for this. But can you please help how to do this?

Comment: Well, sadly I don't know much about Android Canvas drawing, I just noticed it when going over your code. So I can't be of much help with actual best-practise code, but I imagine there are multiple approaches you can take here.

First off, your DrawingZoomingCanvas() method clears the whole canvas for you. What you can do is store any lines you draw in an List and loop through this list at the end of your DrawingZoomingCanvas() method to redraw any lines you previously made.